# Disabling NextJs experimental app directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a real life project and decided to test the new App directory that comes with the Next js 13 version, I noticed some glitches like my images and fonts not loading properly, etc. I would like to stop using the experimental app Dir.
Is there a way to opt out of the experimental app directory locally without having to reinstall next-app?, please I'm new to Next js.

Here is my next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require("path");

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    loader: "akamai",
    path: "/",
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Whenever I put the appDir as false, I get the following error

```bash
Error: > The `app` directory is experimental. To enable, add `appDir: true` to your `next.config.js` configuration under `experimental`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/experimental-app-dir-config
    at Object.findPagesDir (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\lib\find-pages-dir.js:80:19)
    at DevServer.getRoutes (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:141:59)
    at new Server (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:115:47)
    at new NextNodeServer (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:73:9)
    at new DevServer (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:100:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:152:24)
    at C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:165:42
    at async NextServer.prepare (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:134:24)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Favour\OneDrive\Documents\Code School\WebDevelopment\Projects\ecommerce\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\render-server.js:92:17) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation in https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/experimental-app-dir-config

> If you do not want to use the new app/ directory features yet, but have a directory named app/, rename the directory to something else.

Try to rename or remove the `app/` directory and remove the `appDir: true` in your `next.config.js`. If you planning to remove the `app/` directory, move the page files into `src/pages`.

Comment: When deleting the app directory for a statically exported site, I also had to remove `.next/` for `yarn build` to succeed.